# AppGyver Supersonic navigating between Views and creating duplicates

Tags: android, steroids, appgyver, supersonic

I'm using AppGyver Steroids and Supersonic to build an app and I'm having some issues navigating between views programmatically.

Based on the docs, you navigate between views like this:

```
var view_obj = new supersonic.ui.View("main#index");
supersonic.ui.layers.push(view_obj);
```

However, when I inspect things via the Chrome DevTools, it appears that a second duplicate view is created i.e. If I navigate away from the index page and then navigate back, I now have two index pages, instead of what [I think] should be one. It also doesn't close the previous view I was on.

How can I prevent this from happening and simply move to the existing view, instead of duplicating views? How do I close a view after I have navigated away from it?

Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated: thank you for creating both the "appgyver" and "supersonic" tags. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're encountering is that you're creating a `new supersonic.ui.View("main#index")` every time you navigate. On top of this, I think you want to return to the same view when you navigate back to a view for the second time, i.e. you want the view to remain in memory even if it has been removed from the navigation stack with `pop()` (rather than pushing a new instance of that view). For this, you need to preload or "`start()`" the view, as described in the docs [here](http://docs.appgyver.com/supersonic/api-reference/stable/supersonic/ui/views/start/).

I implemented my own helper function to make this easier; here is my code:

```js
start = function(dest, isModal) {
  var viewId=dest,
      view=new supersonic.ui.View({
        location: dest,
        id: viewId
      });
  view.isStarted().then(function(started) {
    if (started) {
      if (isModal) {supersonic.ui.modal.show(view);}
      else {supersonic.ui.layers.push(view);}
    } else {
      // Start Spinner
      supersonic.ui.views.start(view).then(function() {
        if (isModal) {supersonic.ui.modal.show(view);}
        else {supersonic.ui.layers.push(view);}
        // Stop Spinner
      }, function(error) {
        // Stop Spinner
        A.error(error);
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Use it like `start('module#view');`. As a bonus, you can pass `true` as the second argument and it gets pushed as a modal instead.

It checks if you've already started a view - if so, it just pushes that view back onto the stack. If not, it `start()`s (i.e. preloads) it, then pushes it. This ensures that the view stays in memory (with any user input that has been modified) even when you `pop()` it from the stack.

You have to imagine that the layer stack is actually a *stack* in the Computer Science sense. You can only add and remove views at the top of the stack. The consequence of this is that complex navigations such as A > B > C > D > B are difficult/hacky to do (in this case, you'd have to `pop()` D and C in succession to get back to B).

Views will close if you `pop()` them, as long as you *didn't* `start()` them. If you did, and you `pop()` them, they remain in memory. To kill that view, you have to call `stop()` on it, as described in the docs I linked above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this bro, I'll give it a go. As an aside, I would expect a platform like AppGyver to really do a little extra work in abstracting these complex interactions to make it easier for developers.

Comment: Yeah I guess you're right... The problem I think they often come up against is that they need to work within the limitations of *two* operating systems (Android and iOS), while staying as native as possible in both. I think this means that they're restricted to standard, tried-and-tested software patterns like layer stack. The abstractions are all there, you just have to put a bit of work in if you want a really custom implementation. Given that we're not paying a cent, I guess that's fair enough!

Comment: I see your point on being free, but just because water is free doesn't mean you'd drink it dirty. I appreciate all the work AppGyver has done on this, but it should just be easier. I tried your code but it didn't work. It did the same thing. Am I doing something wrong? I already have preloaded views from my `structure.coffee` and I am using `<super-navigate>`, should I disable this functionality and use your function from the beginning?

Comment: Ok, after some tinkering, I disabled everything and used your function to preload the views (instead of using `structure.coffee`) and used controllers to enable movement from view to view (instead of using `<super-navigate>` and it works well. However, I have a form that links to an AJAX function, and I want to redirect back to the previous view on success callback. I used your `start` function, but it doesn't navigate back to the view. Trying to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: One of the errors I get on the console.log is `supersonic.logger.error: supersonic.ui.layers.push rejected: {} Unhandled rejection Error: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. `. Any idea what gives? Cheers.

Comment: Great, glad it's working. I personally think `super-navigate` is one abstraction too far, it requires such a simplified app structure (as far as I can see) that I've never used it. Anyway, your error: when you say 'navigate back', do you mean that the previous view is already on the navigation stack? If so, have you tried `supersonic.ui.layers.pop()` (docs [here](http://docs.appgyver.com/supersonic/api-reference/stable/supersonic/ui/layers/pop/))? That would be the standard correct way to navigate *back*. EDIT: just seen your answer! Glad you've sorted it :)

Comment: Yeah, it was moving back that was my problem. I couldn't understand how everything worked, but I do now. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var view_obj = new supersonic.ui.View("main#index");
supersonic.ui.layers.replace(view_obj);
```

And take a look at [supersonic.ui.layers.pop();](http://docs.appgyver.com/supersonic/api-reference/stable/supersonic/ui/layers/pop/)

Comment: Thanks. `replace` turned out to be the solution, but I had to create some more code to deal my specific challenges. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to LeedsEbooks for helping me get my head around this challenge. I was able to find a solution. Here is the code:

```
  var start = function(route_str, isModal) {

      var regex = /(.*?)#(.*)/g;
      var match_obj = regex.exec(route_str);

      var view_id_str = match_obj[2],
          view_location_str = route_str,
          view = new supersonic.ui.View({
              location: view_location_str,
              id: view_id_str
          });

      view.isStarted().then(function(started) {
          if (started)
          {
              if (isModal)
              {
                  supersonic.ui.modal.show(view);
              }
              else {
                  supersonic.ui.layers.push(view);
              }
          }
          else
          {
              // Start Spinner
              supersonic.ui.views.start(view).then(function() {
                  if (isModal)
                  {
                      supersonic.ui.modal.show(view);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      supersonic.ui.layers.push(view);
                  }
                  // Stop Spinner
              }, function(error) {
                  // Stop Spinner
                  A.error(error);
              });
          }
      });
  };
```

You must ensure that your route has the format `module#view` as defined in the documentation.

**PLEASE NOTE**

There seems to some problem with the *supersonic* ui method for starting views. If you run the following code:

```
supersonic.ui.views.start("myapp#first-view");
supersonic.ui.views.find("first-view").then( function(startedView) {
    console.log(startedView);
});
```

You'll notice that your view `id` and `location` are identical. This seems to be wrong as the `id` should be `first-view` and `location` should be `myapp#first-view`.

So I decided to not use the AppGyver methods and create my own preload method instead, which I run from the controller attached to my home view (this ensures that all the views I want to preload are handled when the app loads). Here is the function to do this:

```
  var preload = function(route_str)
  {
      var regex = /(.*?)#(.*)/g;
      var match_obj = regex.exec(route_str);
      var view = new supersonic.ui.View({
          location: route_str,
          id: match_obj[2]
      });
      view.start();
  };
```

By doing this, I'm sure that the view will get loaded with the right `location` and `id`, and that when I use my `start()` function later, I won't have any problems.

You'll want to make sure that your `structure.coffee` file doesn't have any `preload` instructions so as not to create duplicate views that you'll have problems with later.

Finally, I have a view that is 2 levels in that is a form that posts data via AJAX operation. I wanted the view to go back to the previous view when the AJAX operation was complete. Using my earlier function resulted in the `push()` being rejected. It would be nice if AppGyver Supersonic could intelligently detect that pushing to a previous view should default to a `layers.pop` operation, but you don't always get what you want. Anyway, I managed to solve this using `supersonic.ui.layers.pop()`, which simply does what the Back button would have done.

Everything working as intended now.